# Cannot properly infer object value type by generic key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, inference

I have such interfaces

```js
export type GridColumn<RowData extends object, RowField extends keyof RowData = keyof RowData> = {
    field: RowField;
    renderCell?(cellValue: NonNullable<RowData[RowField]>): ReactNode;
};
```

```js
TableProps<RowData extends object> {
    columns: GridColumn<RowData>[];
    rows: RowData[];
}
```

And such hook which uses it

```js
export const useTable = <RowData extends object>({
...
} as TableProps<RowData>)
```

Code which cannot catch the inferred object value by key

```js
const tableHook = useTable({
    columns: [
            {
                field: "age",
            },
            {
                field: "age2",
                renderCell: (cellValue) => <span>{cellValue.label}</span>
            },
    ],
 rows: [
            {
                age: 11,
                age2: { label: 11 },
            },
            {
                age: 22,
                age2: { label: 22 },
            },
     ]
});
```

Typescript shows error that it cannot define the type of `cellValue`.
It shows the type `{label: string} | number`, but cannot define the inferred type by defined field which is actually the key of `RowData`

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVb4GN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?